# Does the implementation of GDPR compliance per site make sense in terms of good practises?

Tags: standards, implementations

Although I understand privacy concerns, the measure has been imposed by politcians and I want to know what the proper way to put this into place would have been.

Right now, each site has to implement GDPR compliance which is kind of redundant with no promise that your wishes are actually respected.

Wouldn't it make more sense to have a standard and control over settings on the browser side? Or some other way which is closer to the user?

Of course, this question has to do with the actual design or implementation and not the politics.

Comment: "*Of course, this question has to do with the actual design or implementation and not the politics*". Maybe if you'd phrased your question without the political term, "eurocrat", this might be a more believable claim.

Comment: GDPR is nothing to do with browsers and websites, it is about how entire companies handle and individuals' data throughout all systems and processes, software or otherwise. e.g. no browser setting can stop me from farming out your name and address to all my mates' companies.

Comment: @AntP so the screen that pops up when you go on a site has nothing to do with browsers and websites?

Comment: @DavidArno feel free to kick off the politics of it. Belief has to do with impressions and you as a developper do not deal with those unless you're working on front ends.

Comment: @JamesP. the screen is just a message reflecting a business decision, it has nothing to do with the site itself per se. And it certainly won't be enough to be GDPR compliant to just pop up a message telling users their personal data is being stored.

Comment: @jwenting No, GDPR is not just a "business decision". It is the result of a recent European directive and its transposition into local European laws. It applies to all data collected on European citizens and can lead to potentially heavy fines if it is not respected. Plus, someone has to actually program something which has an effect on cookies and so on to reflect privacy preferences. Please read into the subject more as it may affect you if you have a site or are responsible for a site. Which is the focus of the question here.

Comment: @JamesP. the screen reflects how the business decides to deal with the GDPR is what I meant. I know full well what the GDPR is, I've been involved in dealing with its consequences for the companies I work for for over 2 years now at various levels. What's at fault here is your assumption that there's a one size fits all solution to GDPR compliance that's simple to implement as for example a browser plugin.

Comment: @jwenting I understand that. But do you find it logical that user privacy is handled by a company and not the users themselves?

Comment: @JamesP. yes, you as a company that handles user data are responsible for the correct and secure handling of that data. The user is responsible for selecting those companies to handle his data that he feels he can trust to do that correct and secure. And the GDPR forces you as a company handling user data to do just that.

Answer (score 10):

GDPR is about end-to-end privacy. There's no way to implement it only on the browser's side. Every site has to do the work to make sure the personal information is treated with respect for privacy, and provide ways for users to review and remove their information.  While you could have a standardized settings screen in the browser, the vast majority of compliance work should still be done on the website's end.

Browser vendors could still implement such a settings screen if they wish. GDPR does not specify mechanisms, it specifies principles. The actual mechanism by which the principle is achieved is left up to the implementer.

Answer (score 3):

Each individual system and process in a company has to be GDPR compliant. How you accomplish that and what exactly it means will depend on the system or process in question.

For a website, this will likely mean strict rules about log file retention, an option for users to get their data (name, ip addresses, other identifying information) removed from your database and other company systems, things like that.

It's not something that a simple browser plugin can do. In fact a browser plugin won't do anything as the client's computer itself doesn't have to be GDPR compliant, especially not if they are end users.

So you'd need to have a team analysing every single system and process in your company that stores or otherwise retains information that might fall under GDPR rules and then create ways to ensure that that storage or retention is GDPR compliant.
Cleaning up data when no longer needed is just part of that, some data isn't allowed to be stored at all unless there is a direct business requirement (think social security numbers, which can only be stored if required for filing tax returns for example).

There is no one size fits all solution I'm afraid, as not only will the definition of what may be stored and what may not depend on the specific system and sometimes even the specific use of the data within that system but also the storage duration that's allowed and the conditions under which can differ as well.

Answer (score 3):

The GDPR did not appear in a vacuum. Instead, it is largely an updated version of an EU Directive from the 90s. However, Regulations are directly enforceable law across the EU. In combination with the potential of hefty fines, this has caused many data controllers to take their obligations seriously for the first time.

The GDPR is not directly concerned with mandating specific technical measures. Instead, the GDPR requires data controllers to have some data protection process in place that protects data e.g. through reasonable technical and organizational measures. Any data processing must follow the data minimization principle and must be founded on some legal basis such as freely given consent. In some cases the regulation requires specific documents, for example Data Protection Impact Assessments. One of the biggest efforts for GDPR compliance is supply chain security: those that process data on the controller's behalf must now be bound by contracts that limits their use of the data to the controller's instructions.

The GDPR also gives data subjects significant rights, such as a right to access, correct, and delete personal data that a controller has stored about you. Subjects must also be informed in a transparent manner about processing that affects them.

All of these things – having organizational processes, putting contracts in place, giving subjects access to their data – are not things that can be done on the user's end with a browser. This work is often invisible to a user. A website that was compliant with relevant regulations beforehand might have had no user visible changes.

Many websites have decided to implement transparency requirements and to obtain consent via banners or pop-ups. This is in no way necessary for compliance, e.g. they could alternatively refrain from processing that is illegal without consent. (Unfortunately, consent is typically requested for tracking and targeted advertisements, upon which many media websites rely for funding.) Cookie banners may be required, but that is unrelated to the GDPR (→ ePrivacy Directive).

For software engineers, the GDPR means that we have to be mindful of where the systems we create touch on privacy relevant issues. It is a professional obligation to alert stakeholders to  potential problems, and to e.g. involve a Data Protection Officer in a project. But the GDPR is neither a purely engineering or purely legal problem – it is a cross cutting concern that involves the entire organization. Data protection in a software project starts with suitable requirements for that software.

Comment: and it gets worse. Such banners don't indemnify the site operator from GDPR related charges, despite what many seem to think.